# Adding attribute in the node of xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml, ado.net

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL">
 <process id="sid-C3803939-0872-457F-8336-EAE484DC4A04" name="Customer" processType="None" isClosed="false" isExecutable="false">
    <userTask id="Task_1fxai2y" name="ut124" />
  </process>
```

---

This XML I am retrieving from the database, now I have to add the attribute "assignee = abc" in "userTask" tag and save it again to database
I am trying this code, it is not giving any error, but the attribute is not added.

```
  string a;
  SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select * from usertask1 where DIAGRAMID 
                        = " + idnum + "", con);

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader rdr2 =  cmd2.ExecuteReader();
        if (rdr2.HasRows)
        {
            while (rdr2.Read())
            {

                string a = rdr2["XMLFILE"].ToString();// variable 'a' now has the xml

                XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
                xd.LoadXml(a);
              XmlNodeList list = xd.GetElementsByTagName("userTask");
                  XmlAttribute XA = xd.CreateAttribute("ASSIGNEE");
                           XA.Value = "abc";
                           list[0].Attributes.Append(XA);
         }
}
//code to insert the xml again back to DB
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. Check your xml structure or try this approach also

```
    XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
    xd.LoadXml("<root>" +
            "<userTask></userTask>" +
            "<userTask></userTask>" +
        "</root>");
    XmlNodeList list = xd.GetElementsByTagName("userTask");
    XmlElement el = (XmlElement)list[0];
    el.SetAttribute("ASSIGNEE", "abc");
```